# How does Qt on Windows draw exactly? Does it call GDI internal to draw?

Tags: qt, gdi

I'm developer on Windows and I have some experiences on WinAPI programs.
As far as I know, there are two ways to draw on Windows, call GDI (includes wrapper of GDI like GDI+) to do traditional drawing or call some APIs like DX or OpenGL to draw use GPU.
But what other things like Qt are? Does Qt calls GDI finally to draw something? Or it just has its own way to draw directly?
I just want to know its theory in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt widgets use custom software renderer (custom raster engine) - it's not GDI from what it seems.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/topics-graphics.html

every widget inherits from `QPaintDevice` you can check the type of paint device: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpaintengine.html#Type-enum

QtQuick seems to be using [ANGLE (will convert ogl calls to d3d on windows)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANGLE_(software)) / pure OpenGL - https://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/01/18/opengl-implementation-qt-quick-app-using-today/

Answer (score -1):

From the looks of it, since QT 4.0 they had changed the use of GDI and replaced it with some other internals that might improve portability, if you wish, QT is open sourced, so you may look at the code to understand QTGUI.dll internals.

Comment: What the "internals" actually are? you said "portability", but I think it must has a platform-specified implement for Windows. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

I do not know this in practice, but the answer at http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/33565 seems reliable.

UPDATE: This page seems to be more accurate: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-5-on-Windows-ANGLE-and-OpenGL

> Qt 5 on Windows can be configured to use either OpenGL drivers, or
>   DirectX drivers through the ANGLE library. What you want depends on
>   your use case. The Qt project offers binary installers for both
>   variants.      OpenGL
>
> OpenGL (Open Graphics Library) is a wide spread industry standard
>   [opengl.org] for rendering 2D and 3D computer graphics. It’s the
>   de-facto standard for hardware-accelerated graphics operations on Mac
>   OS X, Linux, and most embedded platforms.
>
> OpenGL ES 2.0 (Open Graphics Library for Embedded Systems) is a
>   stripped-down version of OpenGL for use on embedded systems, which is
>   missing some functions.
>
> The Qt Quick 2 stack in Qt 5 is based on OpenGL, and requires OpenGL
>   3.0 (alternatively OpenGL 2.x with the framebuffer_object extension) or higher or OpenGL ES 2.0. The Qt OpenGL module [qt-project.org]
>   requires OpenGL 1.3 or later.      OpenGL on Windows
>
> Although Microsoft Windows has native support for OpenGL since quite
>   some time, the supported standard version (version 1 without any
>   drivers installed) is too limited for Qt . Newer versions are
>   generally available through custom graphics drivers, but require users
>   to install them. Also, the quality of the OpenGL support by some
>   drivers is lacking.    ANGLE Project
>
> ANGLE (Almost Native Graphics Layer Engine) is an open source project
>   [code.google.com] by Google. Its aim is to map OpenGL ES 2.0 API calls
>   to DirectX 9 API. A regularly updated version of it is part of qtbase
>   [qt.gitorious.org] .
>
> To compile Qt with ANGLE you have to have a Direct X SDK
>   [msdn.microsoft.com] installed. Starting from Windows Kit 8, this is
>   included in the Windows SDK.
>
> If ANGLE is used in your application, you should ship
>   d3dcompiler_XX.dll along with the Qt libraries. The version string of
>   the D3D shader compiler is pulled from the DirectX SDK header, so make
>   sure to get the same version that ANGLE was built with (e.g. _43 or
>   _46). This becomes especially important if you configure Qt with -angle-d3d11.     Recommendations Use Desktop OpenGL if Your application uses OpenGL calls not part of OpenGL ES 2.0 Your application does not
>   use OpenGL at all (since ANGLE implies additional deployment
>   dependencies which are then not needed). Your application needs to run
>   on Windows XP. Although it is tempting to use ANGLE as a replacement
>   for missing graphics drivers on this platform, it does not fully work
>   and may lead to crashes, for example, when the security dialog is
>   opened.
>
> Use ANGLE if You need OpenGL ES features, but not full OpenGL You have
>   a heterogeneous user base with different Windows versions & graphics
>   cards You do not want your user to have to install a recent graphics
>   card driver You want to use the video playback functionality of
>   QtMultimedia (see QTBUG-31800 [bugreports.qt-project.org] ) Your
>   application needs to run over Windows Remote Desktop Protocol (see
>   OpenGL and Remote Desktop [social.technet.microsoft.com])
>
> Further Reading
>
> http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/requirements-win.html
>   http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtopengl/qtopengl-index.html
>   http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2012/10/24/graphics-on-windows-from-a-different-angle/
>   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/05/07/hlsl-fxc-and-d3dcompile.aspx